# Both the require and add_template_part function are not including the file

Tags: functions, get-template-part

I'm trying to add a require function in my `functions.php`, to include a file that is in the `wp-content` folder. I first tried this with the function `content_url . 'filename.php'`So the line of code looked like this: `require(content_url . 'filename.php'`. However this made the site crash, because of a `die()` probably. After that I tried to just use the direct link, so `require('http://domainname.com/wp-content/filename.php')`, but this also made the site to crash. Then I tried to use the `add_template_part` function, and for that I of course moved the `filename.php` file into the theme folder. Again this caused the site to crash. It looks like including is not allowed at all, since I can open the files in my browser. For testing purpose I changed the content of `filename.php` to `echo "Form here";`, and if I open this file in my browser directly, I indeed see Form here.

Could there possibly be anything I'm not seeing? Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an URL to include a php file will usually not work. You will need a filesystem path. Depending on where you .php file is located (in this case the template directory), you could use:

```
include( get_template_directory() . '/myfile.php' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

Comment: Ah I see, so why exactly can't I use content_url() then? Is there also a way to get the content directory? Thank you very much for this answer

Comment: Try this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories you would want the constant "WP_CONTENT_DIR". Try to echo your path to get them right.

Comment: content_url is an URL so the included file is not in your filesystem. For php to "reach" your code, it has to be included via the filesystem and not from a remote location like an URL. Hard to explain, sorry :D